# Try-Catch not working for controller to class library [Debugger Mode]

Tags: exception, .net-core

I am running dotnet core 2.* and as the title mentions I have trouble getting my try catch to work when calling from API. And before anyone comments I am also running middle-ware to catch any exceptions. It too doesn't perform as expected

Addinional Information:

- The Two Classes are in different namespaces/projects
- Queries.Authentication is static.
- They are both in the same solution

**Controller**:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public string Login([FromBody] AuthRequest req)
{
    // See if the user exists
    if (Authenticate(req.username, req.password))
    {
        try {
            // Should Fail Below
            UserDetails ud = Queries.Authentication.GetUser(req.username);
        } catch (RetrievalException e){ }
          catch (Exception e){ } // Exception Still Comes Through

    }
}
```

**Queries.Authentication.GetUser Code**:

```
public static class Authentication { 

   public static UserDetails GetUser (string username)
   {
        // Some Code

        if (details.success)
        {
            // Some Code
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RetrievalException(details.errorMessage); // This is not caught propperly

        }
    }
}
```

**Retrieval Exception**:

```
public class RetrievalException : Exception
{
    public RetrievalException()
    {
    }

    public RetrievalException(String message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public RetrievalException(String message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

EDIT: **Adding Middleware Code Here as per request:**

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            HttpStatusCode status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            String message = String.Empty;

            var exceptionType = context.Exception.GetType();
            if (exceptionType == typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException))
            {
                message = "Unauthorized Access";
                status = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else if (exceptionType == typeof(NullReferenceException))
            {
                message = "Null Reference Exception";
                status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
            else if (exceptionType == typeof(NotImplementedException))
            {
                message = "A server error occurred.";
                status = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;
            }
            else if (exceptionType == typeof(RSClientCore.RetrievalException))
            {
                message = " The User could not be found.";
                status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            }
            else
            {
                message = context.Exception.Message;
                status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            }
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;

            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = (int)status;
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
            var err = "{\"message\":\"" + message + "\",\"code\" :\""+ (int)status + "\"}";
            response.WriteAsync(err);
        }
    }
```

**App Config:**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler();
        }
        ...
     }
```

**Service Config:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Model View Controller Support
        services.AddMvc( config =>
            config.Filters.Add(typeof (CustomExceptionFilter))
    );
```

**UPDATE:** After playing around with it I noticed that even though my program throws the exception, if I press continue the API controller then handles it as if the exception was never thrown (as in it catches it and does what I want). So I turned off the break on Exception setting, this fixed it in debugger mode. However this the break doesn't seem to be an issue when I build/publish the program. This makes me think it is definitely a issue with visual studio itself rather than the code.

Comment: Do you have any exception handling middleware `app.UseMiddleware...` configured for your `Web API`? If so - please share the code.

Comment: @DmitryPavlov updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `ExceptionHandled` to `true` that means you have handled the exception and there is kind of no error anymore. So try to set it to `false`.

```
context.ExceptionHandled = false;
```

I agree it looks a bit confusing, [but should do the trick](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5594) you need.

Relevant notes:

- For those who deal with different `MVC` and `API` controller make sure you implemented appropriate `IExceptionFilter` as there are two of them - `System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter` (for `MVC`) and `System.Web.Http.Filters.IExceptionFilter` (for `API`).
- There is a nice article about [Error Handling and ExceptionFilter Dependency Injection for ASP.NET Core APIs](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Oct/16/Error-Handling-and-ExceptionFilter-Dependency-Injection-for-ASPNET-Core-APIs) you could use as a guide for implementing exception filters.
- Also have a look at documentation: [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) (note selector above the left page menu to select `ASP.NET Core 1.0`, `ASP.NET Core 1.1`,`ASP.NET Core 2.0`, or `ASP.NET Core 2.1 RC1`). It has many important notes and explanations why it works as it does.

Comment: Thanx appreciated. I was using Ithe wrong Exception filter